# Como resolver erro Uninitialized string offset: 0 in

Tags: php

Estou usando o Phreeze PHP para criar uma aplicação CRUD mas estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem ao gerar a aplicação, a mensagem é essa:

> Uninitialized string offset: 0 in modifier.lcfirst.php at line 16

O página que tem o código está assim:

```
function smarty_modifier_lcfirst($s) {
     return strtolower( $s{0} ). substr( $s, 1 );
}
```

A página do projeto, se alguém se interessar, é essa:
[Pheeze](http://www.phreeze.com/)

Comment: O que você está passando para a função? Deve dar esse erro se você passar uma string vazia.

Comment: Geralmente a solução é `isset()`

Comment: Olá @rray e bfavaretto obrigado pelas dicas, consegui resolver com o isset().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso aí ocorre porque a `string` não possui o offset `0`. Ou seja, a mesma está vazia.

Exemplo:

```
$a = ''

$a{0}; // PHP error:  Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

Como dito em alguns comentários, você pode utilizar a função `isset` para fazer essa verificação. Também é possível utilizar a função `empty` para saber se a string é vazia.

Você pode alterar a função para  a seguinte forma:

```
smarty_modifier_lcfirst($s) { 

    if (empty($s)) return;

    return strtolower( $s{0} ). substr( $s, 1 );
}
```